# How to parametrize circles on a sphere by the distortion of the equator?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, parametric, spherical-geometry, geodesic

I guess am having a very silly problem right now. Considering a unit sphere $S^2$ and, for example, a curve, in spherical coordinates, $c(t)=(1, \frac{\pi}{2},t)$ that goes around the equator how can I parametrize a family of curves $c(t,s)$ which correspond to rotations of the equator and satisfy $c(0,s)=c(0)$ and $c(\pi,s)=c(\pi)$?

Answer (score 0):

You know that for a suitable choice of coordinate system, [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) $(r,\theta,\varphi)$ correspond to cartesian coordinates $(r\sin\theta\cos\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi,r\cos\theta)$. Specifically, for your equator you have cartesian coordinates $(\cos t,\sin t,0)$. Now you want to rotate that, while keeping $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$ fixed. So you rotate around the $x$ axis, and get something like $(\cos t,\sin t\cos s,\sin t\sin s)$. Now turn that back into spherical coordinates. You have $r=1$ and

\begin{align*}
\cos\theta&=\sin t\sin s \\
\tan\varphi&=\frac{\sin t\cos s}{\cos t}=\tan t\cos s
\end{align*}

So one possible parametrization would be

$$c(t,s)=\bigl(1,\arccos(\sin t\sin s),\arctan(\tan t\cos s)\bigr)$$

except that the $\arctan$ in there only determins an angle modulo $180°$, so it would often end up in the wrong quadrant. You'd have to take the same quadrant as $t$, and one hackish way to express this would be

$$c(t,s)=\bigl(1,\arccos(\sin t\sin s),\arctan(\tan t\cos s)+t-\arctan(\tan t)\bigr)$$

since $t-\arctan(\tan t)$ is exactly the difference between the actual angle $t$ and the angle computed by $\arctan$. You still have to deal with the infinities if $t=(2k+1)\pi/2$.

There might be some clever formula to combine the $\arctan$ and the $\tan$ inside, even though there is an extra factor inside. There might be a way to simplify things choosing a parametrization of the curve which is not constant speed. One might also try to simplify things by expressing the rotation not as an angle, but as something else, e.g. the [tangent of half the angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) or whatever. I haven't explored these options in depth.